# Default type for universal string typeclass

Tags: haskell, typeclass

https://github.com/xich/scotty/issues/26

https://github.com/xich/scotty/pull/27

```haskell
class ScottyString a where
  toContent :: a -> Content
  toText :: a -> T.Text
  fromScotty :: T.Text -> a

instance ScottyString B.ByteString where
  toContent bs = ContentBuilder (fromByteString bs)
  toText bs = toText $ BL.fromChunks [bs]
  fromScotty = B.concat . BL.toChunks . fromScotty

instance ScottyString BL.ByteString where
  toContent bs = ContentBuilder (fromLazyByteString bs)
  toText = decodeUtf8
  fromScotty = encodeUtf8

instance ScottyString T.Text where
  toContent = toContent . encodeUtf8
  toText = id
  fromScotty = id

instance ScottyString String where
  toContent = toContent . T.pack
  toText = T.pack
  fromScotty = T.unpack
```

For me it works fine, but old code is breaked... Because now there is no default type for some functions.

How add default type for this typeclass (for example, **Text**)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BTW, I've started an almost identical Stringable typeclass on hackage: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stringable

Written because I got tired of having to remember how to convert everything to each other.

Comment: Thanks. Good library. Thinking about converting my code to it ;)

Comment: Your stringable package has simplified my life somewhat. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such thing as a default type for a type class. There is a single "global" list of default types, which may be modified using a `default` declaration, however this only works for numeric types and only affects the current module, among other limitations. See the [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-790004.3.4) for details.

You may be able to hack something together using GHC's [`ExtendedDefaultRules`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules), but I suggest you try to resolve the ambiguities in some other way, for example by defining helper functions with a more constrained type.